# Use requests to download webpage that requires cookies into a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I can't get the below code to navigate through the disclaimer page of the website, I think the issue is how I try and collect the cookie.

I want to try and use requests rather than selenium.

```
import requests
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import read_html
    
    # open the page with the disclaimer just to get the cookies
    disclaimer = "https://umm.gassco.no/disclaimer"
    disclaimerdummy = requests.get(disclaimer)
    
    # open the actual page and use the cookies from the fake page opened before
    actualpage = "https://umm.gassco.no/disclaimer/acceptDisclaimer"
    actualpage2 = requests.get(actualpage, cookies=disclaimerdummy.cookies)
    
    # store the content of the actual page in text format
    actualpagetext = (actualpage2.text)
    
    # identify relevant data sources by looking at the 'msgTable' class in the webpage code
    # This is where the tables with the realtime data can be found
    gasscoflow = read_html(actualpagetext, attrs={"class": "msgTable"})
    
    # create the dataframes for the two relevant tables
    Table0 = pd.DataFrame(gasscoflow[0])
    Table1 = pd.DataFrame(gasscoflow[1])
    Table2 = pd.DataFrame(gasscoflow[2])
    Table3 = pd.DataFrame(gasscoflow[3])
    Table4 = pd.DataFrame(gasscoflow[4])
```

Comment: How do you know the `/acceptDisclaimer` path still works? Maybe you should switch to selenium so that you can actually click the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Seeing the website first of all it has only 2 tables and you could use session to use cookies across request instead of storing in a variable follow the below code to get all your expected data it is printing only last 2 rows as I have used tail command, you can modify and get your desired data from those tables.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_html

s=requests.session()
s1=s.get("https://umm.gassco.no")
s2=s.get("https://umm.gassco.no/disclaimer/acceptDisclaimer?")
data = read_html(s2.text, attrs={"class": "msgTable"})
t0 = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
t1 = pd.DataFrame(data[1])

print(t0.tail(2))
print(t1.tail(2))
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks, there used to be a different website with more tables, but the new one only has two, as you pointed out.  The solution was a lot easier than I expected, thanks for your help.